# What site would be appropriate for a 3D Designer?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I have a friend that is a 3D designer and wants to join the Stack Exchange network. We have seen different sites like hardware, English grammar and so on.

Is there any site appropriate for a 3D Developer?

Comment: There is now a site specific to [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with "sections" you mean the different Stack Exchange sites; they're other Q&A sites using the same engine that Stack Overflow does.

There is a Stack Exchange site for [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/), if you're willing to use a site that is specific to one specific piece of software.

Before, there were proposals for a [3D modelling Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-modeling-applications) and an  [Arts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7250/art-creation) site on Area 51, but these proposals didn't make it to become full sites.

Comment: Thank you. He created account but now its UI is different and can't get how to ask question on the same..!! :(

Comment: It's a proposal, the site is not yet live. It currently needs people who "commit" to it. See the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). Off the top of my head, committing requires having a minimum reputation on at least 1 other SE site, so your friend may not yet be able to do this.

Comment: 3D modeling didn't make it, but we do have the software-specific [Blender.SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) now.